# How to keep track if same data is pasted again in MFC edit control?

Tags: mfc

I have implemented paste routine for my edit box.
If the same buffer is pasted again I mean I have kept pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, how can I handle this condition effectively so that my code will be faster?

```
COleDataObject obj;
if (obj.AttachClipboard()) {
    if (obj.IsDataAvailable(CF_TEXT)) {
        HGLOBAL hmem = obj.GetGlobalData(CF_TEXT);
        CMemFile sf((BYTE*) ::GlobalLock(hmem), ::GlobalSize(hmem));
        LPSTR str = buffer.GetBufferSetLength(::GlobalSize(hmem));
        sf.Read(str, ::GlobalSize(hmem));
        ::GlobalUnlock(hmem);
// doing my work here using buffer
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to optimize for the case where the same thing is pasted in repeatedly? As rare as that is, the normal code should be fast enough. And even if it's not rare, the computer is going to execute it sufficiently fast for the user's perception.

Comment: It's not acceptable just to clear the clipboard after the paste?

Comment: What if the user wants to paste the same text twice?

Comment: @patriiice That's never acceptable. The clipboard is a global resource and the only time an application should destroy the contents is when the user initiates a copy/cut operation.